# Django: norm for handling un-created OneToOneFields

Tags: python, django

Here's an example model:

```
class User(models.Model):
   ...
```

Later, I want to add an Invite OneToOne model:

```
# This is arbitrarily named.
class InviteCode(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="invite_code")
   ...


# signals.py
@receivers(signals.post_save, sender=User)
def create_invite_code(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   if created:
      invite_code = InviteCode.objects.create(user=user)
```

Now, for new users I can conveniently do `user.invite_code` for any new users. Is there any standard way to handle this for old users? There seem to be many possible solutions, but none of them seem very clean:

1. I could `try:` `catch RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` every single time I use `user.invite`. This isn't great and seems very unclean.
2. I could create an accessor method, like `get_invite_code` which does the `try/catch`, and always fetch the `user.invite_code` via `user.get_invite_code()`
3. I could run a migration, such that all old users have an Invite Code created, and all new users have an invite code object via the signal.

Anyone have any suggestions on the most pythonic way to handle this?

Comment: Since this is a one time activity you need to perform when you update your schema, migrations are the way to go.

Comment: Mess with old code is always not clear enough. But the most expressive way is the best for me (**Create an accessor method may help you remember that you will be dealing with older cases**). It's personal.